# chrome speed dial with hotkey

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hotkeys

I can't find any speed dial addon for Chrome with hotkey's like in opera or speed dial's from firefox.

In Opera i press STRG + 1 and in the current tab my first speed dial page open's.
In Firefox there are even more hotkeys like strg + shift + 1 for opening the speed dial's first page in a new tab. (STRG+2 for the second page etc)

Is there any possibility to create shortcut's like this?

Comment: I'm also looking for such a plugin but I think this question is more suitable for superuser.com. If you happen to post it there it would be nice if you would provide a link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) API to define keyboard shortcuts in your extension.